# Kann das Objekt Singular sein, wenn das Subjekt Plural ist?

Tags: grammaticality

Wir betrachten die folgenden Sätze:

> Die Reisenden müssen an der Grenze *ihre Pässe / ihren Pass* vorzeigen.
>
> Schaltet bitte *eure Handys / euer Handy* aus.
>
> Es ärgert den Lehrer, wenn die Teilnehmer mit *dem Handy / den Handys* spielen.

Kann man in diesen Beispielen sowohl den Singular als auch den Plural verwenden?

Meine Intuition sagt mir, wenn man aus der Sicht der Empfänger der Mitteilung sieht, kann man sagen, die Aussagen richten sich an jede Einzelperson und da jede Person (angenommen) nur einen Pass oder ein Handy hat, kann man auch den Singular verwenden.

Comment: Ich glaube, die Überschrift stimmt nicht mit der dann ausformulierten Frage überein. Natürlich kann es Sätze geben mit einem Subjekt im Singular und einem  Objekt (oder gar mehreren davon) im Plural:  *Maria schenkt ihren Neffen fünf Säcke Äpfel.* Subjekt im Singular, Dativobjekt im Plural, Akkusativobjekt im Plural. - Bessere Überschrift?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Die Überschrift finde ich selbst auch nicht so treffend. Es ist mir aber nichts Besseres eingefallen. Hast du vielleicht einen Vorschlag?

Comment: Ich habe da auch schon ziemlich herumgegrübelt, bin aber auf nichts Brauchbares gekommen. Irgendwie geht's um Kongruenz von grammatischem Numerus und Anzahl der außersprachlichen Referenzobjekte sowie um deren Verhältnis untereinander. Aber wenn man das in der Überschrift so schreibt, versteht keiner, um was es geht. Mit der gegenwärtigen Überschrift zwar auch nicht, aber immerhin regt sie zum Lesen an...

Answer (score 3):

In einer anderen Antwort wurde die These aufgestellt, dass Singular zwingend anzuwenden sein, weil jede Person (vorausgesetzterweise) nur einen Pass hat, nicht mehrere.

Versuchen wir es mal experimentell. Jede Person hat bekanntlich nur jeweils eine Nase und einen Kopf.

> Der Behördenleiter sagte den Bürgern, sie sollten **ihre Nase** nicht überall reinstecken.
>   Der Behördenleiter sagte den Bürgern, sie sollten **ihre Nasen** nicht überall reinstecken.

Hier wäre ich für Singular. Vielleicht hängt dies aber mit der Redewendung "die Nase überall reinstecken" zusammen, die eben etablierterweise die Nase im  Singular verwendet.

Also nächster Versuch, ohne Störeinfluß etablierter Wendungen:

> Der Baustellenleiter sagte den Besuchern, sie sollten auf **ihren Kopf** achtgeben.
>   Der Baustellenleiter sagte den Besuchern, sie sollten auf **ihre Köpfe** achtgeben.

In diesem Fall klingt der Satz für mich mit Köpfen im Plural normaler, mit Kopf im Singular eher schräg. Die Besucher haben gleichwohl jeweils nur einen Kopf, und der Satz mit Plural ruft bei mir nicht das Bild eines Baustellenbesuchs durch eine Delegation von Hydren auf.

Ähnlich geht es mir bei:

> Die Reisenden müssen an der Grenze ihren Pass vorzeigen.
>  
>   Die Reisenden müssen an der Grenze ihre Pässe vorzeigen.

Mit Pässen im Plural klingt es für mich normaler.

Dies alles ist allerdings keine grammatische Frage. Eher **eine Frage des Stils sowie der Perspektive**: Aus Sicht des Baustellenleiters sind dort viele Köpfe, die an einen Balken stoßen können. Aus Sicht des einzelen Besuchers ist jeweils nur auf einen einzigen Kopf aufzupassen. Aus Sicht des Grenzbeamten sind es viele Pässe, die einzusammeln sind. Aus Sicht des Reisenden ist jeweils nur ein einziger Pass vorzuzeigen.

Entsprechend kann man im Falle der Handys auch beide Varianten einsetzen, je nach Perspektive auf die Sache:

> Es ärgert den Lehrer, wenn die Teilnehmer mit dem Handy spielen.

Dies nimmt die Teilnehmer als einzelne in den Blick.

> Es ärgert den Lehrer, wenn die Teilnehmer mit den Handys spielen.

Dies nimmt die gesamte Gruppe in den Blick.

Comment: Ich denke, es ist tatsächlich bei einer 1:1 Beziehung der Singular angebracht. Der Baustellenleiter wird den Satz "Bitte achten Sie auf Ihren Kopf" verwendet haben. Im Gegensatz dazu "Die Reisenden müssen an der Grenze ihre Koffer vorzeigen.", da hier die Menge unbestimmt ist. Wenn die Aussage auf jeden einzelnen anzuwenden ist und keine Ausnahme gestattet, dann Singular.

Comment: @Holger  Ich würde auch hier beide Varianten für möglich und in freier Wildbahn antreffbar halten: "Liebe Besucherinnen und Besucher, wir haben niedrige Türen hier, bitte passen Sie auf Ihre Köpfe auf." - "Liebe Besucherinnen und Besuchern, wir haben niedrige Türen hier, bitte passen Sie auf Ihren Kopf auf." - Bei den Koffern kommt etwas anderes hinzu: In einer Normalsituation wird man davon ausgehen, dass etliche Reisende mehrere Koffer haben. Es wäre also unnatürlich, in einer Ansprache an die Reisenden den Koffer im Singular zu halten.

Comment: Ich habe noch hinzugefügt: "Wenn die Aussage auf jeden einzelnen anzuwenden ist und keine Ausnahme gestattet, dann Singular".Das passt auch auf Dein Beispiel im Kommentar. Ich würde da nie "Köpfe" verwenden.

Comment: @Holger  Das gestehe ich Dir gerne zu. Ich meine aber, man trifft in der Sprachwirklichkeit beide Verwendungsformen, und meine These ist nun, dass keine davon als *falsch* bezeichnet werden kann. Vielmehr drücken sie eine unterschiedliche Perspektive aus.

Comment: Ja, das mit der Perspektive passt. Beispiel mit den Handyspielern. Deckt sich netterweise auch mit meiner Ansicht. Wenn nicht ausnahmslos jeder spielt, Plural.

Comment: Die inhaltliche Vertretbarkeit beider Lösungen spiegelt sich in den unterschiedlichen Gebräuchen verschiedener Sprachen wider. Der Deutsche sagt tendentiell "Viele Menschen verloren *ihr Leben*", während es im Englischen heißt "*their lives*". M.E. gibt es keine tiefere Begründung, weshalb einer dieser etwa gleichwertigen Alternativen üblich wurde.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn jede Person (angenommen) nur einen Pass oder ein Handy hat, wird man in der Regel den Singular verwenden. Offenbar gibt es Ausnahmen, siehe: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Kongruenz-im-Numerus

Comment: Referenz? Begründung? Das ist ein bisschen dünn....

Comment: Beispiele und Überlegungen dazu siehe andere Antwort auf dieser Seite. Ich komme dort eher zu einem anderen Schluss.

Comment: Ich denke, wenn die Aussage auf jeden einzelnen anzuwenden ist und keine Ausnahme gestattet, dann kann im Singular formuliert werden.